# C++ : Is Namespaces definition allowed before '#include <files>' .

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am using a single namespace in multiple files and I have inserted "namespace abc {" at the start and "}" at the end of each of file through a script (except main). Therefore '#include " comes under the namespace in each file. 
When I compile, it doesn't work (not recognizing the system functions etc).

But if I define namespace after the '#include ' lines, everything works fine. 
what is the problem here?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that by putting the headers inside a namespace, you're making them declare functions in that namespace -- but the definitions (implementations) of those functions don't exist in that namespace, so when you link, they can't be found and linking fails.

To give a concrete example, let's say you had a header that declared a function `int f(int)`. By enclosing that inside the braces for a namespace, you're turning that into a declaration for `int somenamespace::f(int)`.

While `int ::f(int)` has been defined, `int somenamespace::f(int)` hasn't, so you can't link.

Note that this doesn't apply to `extern "C"` functions. They basically ignore namespaces, so (for example) something like:

```
namespace x {
    #include <stdio.h>
}
```

won't affect the normal C functions in `stdio.h`.

Comment: That isn't quite true, I believe. If you do that, then you will still have to use x::printf. However, that will still link OK, bexcause the extern "C" affects the name mangling.

Answer (score 1):

`#include` lines should go before namespace definitions, otherwise you might get unexpected results. The preprocessor language is different from the c/c++ code and mixing them might produce hard to track bugs.

Comment: Thanx Alexander, 
Actually, There are lots of files and It would be a hard job to insert namespace definition in each file manually (i.e. after the preprocessor declarations). Thats why I inserted them at the starting through a script.